# BrainTree UIDropIn VC not display amount in iOS integration

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, paypal, braintree

I create a demo for payment using Braintree iOS v4 SDK. All thinks going great but I have a query regarding the amount. I used DropIN VC for UI.

```
 //MARK: Show Dropin VC
func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String) {
    let request =  BTDropInRequest()
    request.amount = "1.0"
    request.currencyCode = "USD"
    request.threeDSecureVerification = true;

    let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request)
    { (controller, result, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("ERROR")
        } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
            print("CANCELLED")
        } else if let result = result {

            if (result.paymentOptionType == BTUIKPaymentOptionType.applePay){
                controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.paymentApplePay()
            }else{
                print(result.paymentMethod?.nonce as Any)
                print(result.description)
            }

        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

when I select Paypal option I redirect to the checkout screen. check images
[image]

[image]

here is the problem that I can't see the amount I entered at the time of the request. How can I see that? Thanks in advance.